# In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, how can I generate specific XML tags?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am not familiar with generating XML code from SQL. 
After doing some research, I think I need to use a statement like: `FOR XML EXPLICIT`, `FOR XML RAW` or `FOR XML AUTO`, but when I run it on `AUTO`, the output is a row like this:

```
<student externalStudentID1="100003" lastName="Smith" externalSiteId="Place"/>
```

That is close to what I need, but it has to have specific opening and closing tags like:

```
<student externalStudentID1="100003" externalSiteId="Place"></student>
```

When I tried using `ELEMENTS`, `RAW`, or `PATH` I ended up with opening and closing tags for all of the elements. `EXPLICIT` just threw errors and would require rewriting the entire select statement. Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
SELECT [externalStudentId1] as StudId, (    
SELECT [externalStudentId1],[externalStudentId2],[socialSecurityNumber],sbl.fn_ToSblDate ( [birthDate]) as [birthDate],[lastName],[firstName],[middleName],[informalName],[nameTitle] ,[nameSuffix],[externalCampusId],[externalSiteId]   
FROM sbl.[student] as student     
WHERE student.externalStudentId1=stud.externalStudentId1   
FOR XML Auto   
) as SblData   
FROM sbl.[student] as stud   
WHERE stud.[ExcludeFromSbl] =0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate both open and close tag you can add empty inner text node. For example.

```
SELECT
    externalStudentId1 AS '@externalStudentID1',
    externalSiteId AS '@externalSiteId',
    ...
    '' AS 'text()' -- This empty string as inner text is added
FROM
    sbl.[student]
FOR
    XML PATH('student')
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it added tags to all of the fields.  All I need is the opening and closing student tags.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get, how can it "add tags to all of the fields". It just create tags you've manually set. In the sample this is only <student> tag and two attributes exactly as in your example: "<student externalStudentID1="100003" externalSiteId="Place"></student>". Can you explain in more details the error?

Comment: It places opening and closing tags in front of each element like this:  <student><externalStudentID1>100003</externalStudentID1><birthDate>1980-01-05</birthDate>....</student>

Comment: I don't know why it did; it just did!

Comment: It seems you've missed "@" symbol in the aliases. If it is omitted then value is put in tag. So "SELECT externalStudentId1" or "SELECT externalStudentId1 as 'externalStudentId1'" will cause the values to be wrapped by tags. But "externalStudentId1 as '@externalStudentId1'" will put it into attribute.

Comment: WOW! That was the problem!  You are a genius!  Thank you so very much for your help.  I cannot thank you enough.  I hope you have an awesome day today! :)